# GithubへのアクセスをSSHではなくHttpsでやりたい

Tags: git, github

https://employment.en-japan.com/engineerhub/entry/2017/01/31/110000

こちらのサイトを参考にGithubを設定していましたが
私のプロキシ環境下ではGithubにアクセスできず,聞いたところによると
sshではなくhttpsではアクセスできるそうです。

やり方がわかりません
教えていただけないでしょうか

環境はWindows10です

Answer (score 1):

Github の ヘルプに書いてあるのでこちらを試してみてください。

https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended

**追記** httpsで利用する際に参考URLのどこの内容が変わってくるか記載します。

https://employment.en-japan.com/engineerhub/entry/2017/01/31/110000

**GitHubへのSSH接続を確認する**

- 接続できないとのことなので飛ばしていいです。

**GitHubで作成したリポジトリ名をコピーする**

- GitHubのサイトで、リポジトリのページの右側の「Clone or download」をクリックし、最初の「Clone with HTTP」の状態のまま。URLをコピーします。
- 「https://github.com/【ユーザー名】//【リポジトリ名】.git」みたいなURLが取得できます
- 下記のようにコマンドを実行してローカルにリポジトリをコピーしてください。
- `git clone https://github.com/【ユーザー名】//【リポジトリ名】.git`

**GitHubへプッシュする**

- githubのヘルプによれば、pushを実行した時にでGithubのID/PASSが聞かれます。
- 登録したID/PASSを入力して pushがうまくいくか確認してください。

以上の部分が https で Githubリポジトリを操作した時に、参考URLの内容と変わってくると思います。

Comment: 本当に申し訳ないのですがそれを見てもよくわからなかったのです…

Comment: remote -v https://………みたいな感じで登録することがhttpsでのアクセスなのでしょうか？それでもTimeoutしてしまいます

Comment: @仲井間砂廣 参考にした記事のどの部分が変わってくる追記いたしました

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！